# CASE WHEN Statement in the Filter

Tags: sql, mysql, case

For example there are two tables t1 and t2:

t1 as, the only value in the table is either 'Prime', 'Non-Prime' or **'All'**. So it's something like this below, shipment_type can be one of the three values. It's 'Prime' in this example. 'All' means it can be either Prime or Non-Prime.

```
   shipment_type 
   Prime
```

and t2 as:

```
order_day   customer_id shipment_type   order_total
2/1/2024    118XXXXXXX  Prime   181.9
1/24/2024   118XXXXXXX  Prime   71.49
1/29/2024   118XXXXXXX  Non-Prime   814.38
1/29/2024   118XXXXXXX  Non-Prime   814.38
```

I want to filter table t2 based on the value in the t1 table but I don't know how to select all of the values in t2 table if shipment_type in the table t1 is 'All'.

I tried to filter table t2 like this, however this only includes Prime or Non-Prime results. I want to obtain all of the values in the t2 table if t1.shipment_type  = 'All'

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t2
    WHERE
    t2.shipment_type = (SELECT CASE WHEN t1.shipment_type = 'Prime' THEN 'Prime' 
    WHEN t1.shipment_type = 'Non-Prime' THEN 'Non-Prime' 
    END AS customer_type 
    FROM t1)
```

I don't think adding the third condition in case when will help since there is no 'All' field in table t2.

Thanks and appreciating your response

Comment: What is the _relationship_ between the two tables?

Comment: t1 table is only one row, shipment_type field is in also t2 but t1 is mainly is used to filter table t2

Comment: Can you update the question with table description some data example and expected result ?

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use the `CASE` clause. Simply use an `INNER JOIN`.

The condtion `OR t1.shipment_type = 'All'` ensures that all records from t2 are retrieved if t1.shipment_type = 'All' :

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.shipment_type = t2.shipment_type OR t1.shipment_type = 'All';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cuJDUePC)

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I myself made the solution more complex than it should be :)

Comment: OR in JOIN conditions is not a good idea. It can be rewrite with UNION